# How do I import external audio into the Voice Memos app?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos-mojave

I have hundreds of .m4a recordings sitting on my iMac that were not recorded in the Voice Memos app but instead recorded with an external audio device. I would like to import them into Voice Memos so they can be synced with my entire Voice Memos collection. Is there a way—unofficial or not—to import audio that was not originally recorded in Voice Memos into the Voice Memos app?

Happy to do this either via Mojave or iOS.